# Breakpoint on property change

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, google-chrome, firebug

Firebug for Firefox has a nice feature, called "Break on property change", where I can mark any property of any object, and it will stop JavaScript execution right before the change.

I'm trying to achieve the same in Google Chrome, and I can't find the function in Chrome debugger. How do I do this in Google Chrome?

Comment: If you want to do this with HTML elements see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32686203/308851

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If you don't mind messing around with the source, you could redefine the property with an accessor.

```
// original object
var obj = {
    someProp: 10
};

// save in another property
obj._someProp = obj.someProp;

// overwrite with accessor
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'someProp', {
    get: function () {
        return obj._someProp;
    },

    set: function (value) {
        debugger; // sets breakpoint
        obj._someProp = value;
    }
});
```

Comment: is there a plug in which  would do that for me?

Comment: @ArsenZahray, dunno. However, you can make a handy function out of it and use like `console.watch(obj, 'someProp')`.

Comment: This does not work for built-in properties such as `window.location` for security reasons.

Comment: To debug setters for DOM elements this pattern should be slightly modified. See https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/how-to-debug-javascript-to-find-code-which-modifies-your-dom/ for more details

Comment: @katspaugh can i ask why you need to this `obj._someProp = obj.someProp;`, it seems unrelated regarding what you are trying to archieve (probably because i'm missing somethign)

Comment: Found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256087/object-define-property-for-getter-and-setter that explains why it is needed

Answer (score 119):

**Edit 2016.03: `Object.observe` is deprecated and removed in Chrome 50**

**Edit 2014.05: `Object.observe` was added in Chrome 36**

Chrome 36 ships with native `Object.observe` implementation that can be leveraged here:

```javascript
myObj = {a: 1, b: 2};
Object.observe(myObj, function (changes){
    console.log("Changes:");
    console.log(changes);
    debugger;
})
myObj.a = 42;
```

If you want it only temporarily, you should store callback in a variable and call `Object.unobserve` when done:

```
myObj = {a: 1, b: 2};
func = function() {debugger;}
Object.observe(myObj, func);
myObj.a = 42;
Object.unobserve(myObj, func);
myObj.a = 84;
```

Note that when using `Object.observe`, you'll not be notified when the assignment didn't change anything, e.g. if you've written `myObj.a = 1`.

To see the call stack, you need to enable "async call stack" option in Dev Tools:

[image: chrome async call stack]

---

**Original answer (2012.07):**

A `console.watch` sketch as suggested by @katspaugh:

```javascript
var console = console || {}; // just in case
console.watch = function(oObj, sProp) {
   var sPrivateProp = "$_"+sProp+"_$"; // to minimize the name clash risk
   oObj[sPrivateProp] = oObj[sProp];

   // overwrite with accessor
   Object.defineProperty(oObj, sProp, {
       get: function () {
           return oObj[sPrivateProp];
       },

       set: function (value) {
           //console.log("setting " + sProp + " to " + value); 
           debugger; // sets breakpoint
           oObj[sPrivateProp] = value;
       }
   });
}
```

Invocation:

```
console.watch(obj, "someProp");
```

Compatibility:

- In Chrome 20, you can paste it directly in Dev Tools at runtime!
- For completeness: in Firebug 1.10 (Firefox 14), you have to inject it in your website (e.g. via Fiddler if you can't edit the source manually); sadly, functions defined from Firebug don't seem to break on `debugger` (or is it a matter of configuration? please correct me then), but `console.log` works.

Note that in Firefox, `console.watch` already exists, due to Firefox's non-standard [`Object.watch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch). Hence in Firefox, you can watch for changes natively:

```
>>> var obj = { foo: 42 }
>>> obj.watch('foo', function() { console.log('changed') })
>>> obj.foo = 69
changed
69
```

Edit: `Object.watch` was removed in Firefox 57.

Comment: By the way, it seems being unable to hit debugger in custom code is a regression between Firebug 1.8 and 1.9: [issue 5757](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5757) -> duplicate of [issue 5221](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5221)

Comment: What is the purpose / benefit of saving the object value into the sPrivateProp variable, and then retrieving through that variable?

Comment: @ColeReed we must store the value somewhere to retrieve it in the getter; it can not be stored in `oObj[sProp]`, because the getter would enter an infinite recursion. Try it in Chrome, you'll get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Comment: Isn't there a Chrome extension to add this console method? It's awesome! :-D

Comment: `Object.observe` / and the `"console.watch"` I wrote only works with JS objects. For DOM objects, you can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). See them in action [here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/mutation-observers/). Note though that in Chrome Dev Tools debugger, you can put "DOM breakpoints" instead.

Comment: I"d like to add this, as the `async` checkbox is so golden with this approach:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

Comment: This is useful in itself, but alas, unless I miss something, in current Chrome (48), we can see only the changes, not the call stack, so we don't know where it has been changed. And it seems to accumulate / group changes.

Comment: @PhiLho it's possible to see the stack, with the `async` checkbox as @cnp wrote, see my update

Comment: Thanks, I will try. The linked article is about async APIs, so I thought it was off-topic... Meanwhile, I tried Firefox' object.watch which gives the call stack. That gives us some useful tools in our quiver (or arrows in our toolbox?).

Comment: Should update this answer: `Object.observe` is deprecated and soon will be removed: see: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6147094632988672

Comment: Right,  I knew it was deprecated but didn't know they finally decided to remove it in Chrome 50. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer to indicate that the function was removed! Too many answers are stale...

Comment: Though `Object.watch` no longer exists, Firefox can still observe property changes, see https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/12/debugging-variables-with-watchpoints-in-firefox-72/

Answer (score 118):

There is a library for this:  [BreakOn()](https://github.com/paulirish/break-on-access)

If you add it to Chrome dev tools as a snippet *(sources --> [snippets](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/sources/#snippets) --> right-click --> new --> paste [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulirish/break-on-access/master/break-on-access.js) --> run)*, you can use it anytime.

[image]

---

To use it, open the dev-tools and run the snippet.  Then to break when `myObject.myProperty` is changed, call this from the dev-console:

```
breakOn(myObject, 'myProperty');
```

You could also add the library to your project's debug-build so you don't need to call `breakOn` again every time you refresh the page.

Comment: Best solution for anyone trying to debug from dev console. No extra effort to reuse on any website, awesome!

Comment: Awesome tool find! Such a massive time saver for debugging complex code.

Comment: This didn't break when `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` were changing. This helped me realize that there is no JavaScript involved when the user's mousewheel scrolling modifies these values. (Whether they change is influenced by `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` in the SCSS style.)

Answer (score 6):

This can also be done by using the new [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object whose purpose is exactly that: intercepting the reads and writes to the object that is wrapped by the Proxy. You simply wrap the object you would like to observe into a Proxy and use the new wrapped object instead of your original one.

Example:

```
const originalObject = {property: 'XXX', propertyToWatch: 'YYY'};
const watchedProp = 'propertyToWatch';
const handler = {
  set(target, key, value) {
    if (key === watchedProp) {
      debugger;
    }
    target[key] = value;
  }
};
const wrappedObject = new Proxy(originalObject, handler);
```

Now use wrappedObject where you would supply originalObject instead and examine the call stack on break.

Comment: Proxy's `set` must return `true` for it not to fail for other than tracked cases.

Answer (score 5):

```
function debugProperty(obj, propertyName) {
  // save in another property
  obj['_' + propertyName] = obj[propertyName];

  // overwrite with accessor
  Object.defineProperty(obj, propertyName, {
    get: function() {
      return obj['_' + propertyName];
    },

    set: function(value) {
      debugger; // sets breakpoint
      obj['_' + propertyName] = value;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Decided to write my own version of this solution, save it in a snippet in Chrome's DevTools, and wrapped it in an IIFE that should support both Node and Browsers. Also changed the observer to use a scope variable rather than a property on the object, such that there is no possibility of name clashes, and any code that enumerates keys will not "see" the new "private key" that is created:

```
(function (global) {
  global.observeObject = (obj, prop) => {
    let value

    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
      get: function () {
        return value
      },

      set: function (newValue) {
        debugger
        value = newValue
      },
    })
  }
})(typeof process !== 'undefined' ? process : window)
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on the excellent solution by Alexandos Katechis, here is a version of the snippet that does not disturb the original value of the property. I renamed it to better match what I'm thinking when I use it.

Usage:

1. Add the snippet via Sources -> Snippets
2. When needed, press Command-O and choose to run the breakOnChange snippet
3. Call `breakOnChange(anyObject, 'propertyName')` in the console
4. Take the action that causes the change
5. Stops in debugger

This is very helpful for spotting things like a global library such as jQuery being stomped on by a third-party script.

```js
(function (global) {
  global.breakOnChange = (obj, prop) => {
    let value = obj[prop]

    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
      get: function () {
        return value
      },

      set: function (newValue) {
        debugger
        value = newValue
      },
    })
  }
})(typeof process !== 'undefined' ? process : window)
```

Answer (score -4):

Chrome has this feature built-in in latest versions https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/view-and-change-your-dom-breakpoints.

So no more needs for custom libraries and solutions, just right click on DOM element in the inspector and choose 'Break on' -> 'attribute modifications' and that's it.

Comment: He asked for (js object) property change, not DOM attribute value change

Comment: @Ivica This is a good technique, but this is the wrong place to put it.  It would be fine as a comment, but not as an answer.