# Break on variable change in Chrome using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome, breakpoints

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618278/how-to-break-on-property-change-in-chrome) question, I would like to break on a variable change in Chrome. However, I'm using Angular, so the variable I would like to break on is only defined in the HTML. Its essentially something like this -

```
<div ng-click="show = !show">...<div>
<div ng-class="{expanded : show}">...
```

With no code in the controller. So how can I get Chrome to pause when `show` is changed? I know that I can change the code to a function call that wraps `show` and then put a breakpoint there, but its an inefficient use of time and I would like to know if there is a way to directly break on variable change.

Comment: There *is* a way to do it but it would be an even more "inefficient use of time".  You would have to put a breakpoint inside AngularJs's `ng-click` or `$watch` code but that would most likely be fired so many times that you would be constantly hitting the breakpoint

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can achive the desired feature via console:

1. First get access to the scope, on which `show` property is defined. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-angular-scope-variable-in-browsers-console)
   is an explanation of how you can do this.
2. Then you may observe changes of this scope object via Chrome's `Object.observe`.

To simplify this process you may define global function like this one:

```
function breakOn(property, object) {
    Object.observe(object, function (changes) {
      changes.forEach(function (change) {
        if (change.name === property) {
          console.log("Property " + property + " changed");
          console.log(change);
          debugger;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

And then after step 1 type in the console: `breakOn('show', $scope);`

Comment: Object.observe was removed from Chrome, starting from Chrome 50 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195945/object-observe-remove-in-chrome-50