# Object.observe remove in chrome 50

Tags: google-chrome, deprecated, object.observe

I had a warning message in Chrome, this one notice that `Object.observe` method is deprecated and will be removed in Chrome 50 around April 2016.

Have you an alternative solution to replace `Object.observe` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So it was depricated and will be removed  because of some problem with perfomance. Please see this link http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/11/object-observe-withdrawn

I think you should look into RxJS library and it's Observable

> Using RxJS, you can represent multiple asynchronous data streams (that
>   come from diverse sources, e.g., stock quote, tweets, computer events,
>   web service requests, etc.), and subscribe to the event stream using
>   the Observer object. The Observable notifies the subscribed Observer
>   instance whenever an event occurs.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/