# Global variable became undefined after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the html page I have some js code, which loads an js file called cartjs in $(window).load like below:

```
<script>
  //var cart = {};
  var loadJsAsync = {
    load: function(sourceUrl, id) {
      var js, fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      var that = this;
      if (document.getElementById(id)) {
        that.callbacks.forEach(function (fn, index) {
          console.log(fn, index);
          fn();
        });
        return;
      }
      js = document.createElement('script');
      js.type = 'text/javascript';
      js.ansyc = true;
      js.id = id;
      js.src = sourceUrl;
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      $('#' + id).on('load', function() {
        that.callbacks.forEach(function (fn, index) {
          console.log(fn, index);
          fn();
        });
      });    
    },
    callbacks: []
  };

  $(window).load(function () {
    loadJsAsync.load("<%= ScriptSourceUrl %>", 'cartjs');
  });
</script>
```

The callbacks is where I put functions dependent on the **Object cart** defined in cartjs. When I refresh the entire page, everything is good, and there are no dependency problems.

When an ajax call is fired to partially update some data in the page, the #cartjs script tag is still there, while the **cart Object** will become undefined and the code

```
 if(document.getElementById(id)) {
     that.callbacks.forEach(function (fn, index) {
         console.log(fn, index);
         fn();
     });
     return;
 }
```

will also complain the cart Object is undefined.

However, if I define a global **cart object** before the loadJsAsync by removing the comment in the first line, the **cart object** will no longer become undefined after refresh, and the depending functions will no longer complain.

Does anyone kindly know how to explain it?

Comment: It looks like your problem is in a different file - I don't see your `cart` variable anywhere!

Comment: @Chris The cart is defined in the cartjs file, which is loaded by loadJsAsync. The cartjs file just defined this cart object and its functions/properties. I don't think the problem is in that file.

Comment: It's also the only code that's trying to use it or somehow setting it to undefined. As is, we're left guessing to what could be going wrong.

Comment: Using the Object.observe method might provide an answer. See post by jakub here: [How to “break on property change” in chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618278/how-to-break-on-property-change-in-chrome)

Comment: @Chris That is a library file and has 4000+ lines of code, it is really hard to put it here. If we just assume cartjs does not make the cart to undefined, what might be the possible explanation?