# Which function changes a variable

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a variable `foo` which value changes from time to time. My code is huge,
so I dont know where it is changed.

I want to know whether there is a possibility to know where the value of `foo` is manipulated. I don't care if i can solve it through the chrome debugger or via javascript code.

are there possibilities to do this?

Comment: what about adding break points in your javascript console? this is a nice tutorial: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: thanks, but i did consider this option but it is too much of an argy-bargy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add an object.observe directly into chrome dev tools to get a console message when your property changes. Take a look at this: [How to "break on property change" in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618278/how-to-break-on-property-change-in-chrome)

look for the answer that uses object.observe

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `foo`, you could do it like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "foo", { 
    set: function (x) { this.value = x; console.trace() }, 
    get: function() { return this.value; }
});
```

Then, anytime `foo` is set it will run `console.trace()`.

[image]

Comment: Forgot about this.value in defineProperty.

Answer (score 1):

As @ChadMcGrath pointed out `Object.observe` is probably what you want, but some other options are available, for example if a variable is a property on an object you could define a setter for it:

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, "myProperty",{ 
  set: function (x) {
    console.log("Set myProperty to", x);
    console.trace();
    this.value = x; 
  },
  get: function () {
    return this.value;
  },
});
```

With ECMAScript 2015 you can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but this doesn't work in most browsers yet:

```
var handler = {
    set: function(target, name, value, receiver){
        console.log("Set", name, "to", value);
        console.trace();
        target[name] = value;
    }
};

var o = new Proxy({}, handler);
o.myProperty = 1; //Will console log and give you a trace.
```