# Chrome breakpoint on radio doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

I have a page where some JavaScript modifies a radio button to be not checked and another to be checked -- the HTML source contains the right checked attributes but when inspecting, the wrong one is checked. Also, when loading with JS off, the right one is checked. So I put a Chrome breakpoint on both for attribute modification and the breakpoints do not fire when reloading. I tried to set a breakpoint on a common parent div and it still doesn't fire.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Code...? There's a ton of JS on this page, I didn't write it, not sure what are you asking for. I added a screenshot of the Chrome Inspector.

Comment: Once the page is rendered, `checked` is a *property* that may be changed via JS. You won't necessarily see that change reflected in the element's attributes

Comment: Then what should I break on? (I naively thought "checked" is an HTML attribute.)

Comment: You could try the suggestions here ~ http://stackoverflow.com/a/11658693/283366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil's comment is helpful but it needs just a little love. First, check the Async checkbox

[image]

in the Sources tab just next to the Call Stack. Otherwise you won't get a useful call stack. Then add this snippet:

```
<script>
var debugel  = document.getElementById("edit-field-slideshow-media-type-und-images");
Object.observe(debugel, function(changes) {
  console.log(changes);
  debugger;
});
</script>
```

Between the console and the debugger you have a reasonable chance to figure out what happens.

Comment: Object.observe doesnt seem to exist anymore, console says it is not a function

Comment: Although not necessarily the easiest/quickest, when all else fails this works: https://github.com/paulirish/break-on-access. I used it to find when an `input` textbox value was getting changed. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38646109.