# Javascript Chrome Debugging: Tracking Mutations

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Given some variable set by `file1.js`, .e.g:

```
window.someVar = 'foo';
```

And some code executed later that mutates the variable in `file2.js`, e.g.

```
window.someVar = 'bar';
```

Is there some way that, in Chrome DevTools (or some plain JS solution), I can trigger a breakpoint or view a callstack whenever `window.someVar` is mutated, so that I can track which source file(s) are mutating it?

Comment: Write `debugger;` before this statement..

Comment: I'm aware of this - what I'm asking is, given that I don't know what code is mutating it, I want to track down the code that is. @RayonDabre

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11618397/561731 is an awesome answer and should work with what you need :-)

Comment: Or create `console.watch` as in the other answer over there.

Comment: @Neal Exactly what I was looking for - thank you!

Comment: Happy to help @CooperMaruyama :-)