# Object define property for getter and setter

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

I'm getting an error on Maximum call stack size for this code.

```
function ValueObject() {
}

ValueObject.prototype.authentication;

Object.defineProperty(ValueObject.prototype, "authentication", {
    get : function () {
        return this.authentication;
    },
    set : function (val) {
        this.authentication = val;
    }
});

var vo = new ValueObject({last: "ac"});
vo.authentication = {a: "b"};
console.log(vo);
```

Error

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: That's because the `set` function is executed each time the assignment happens. There is no point in using `defineProperty` in your code. What you are defining is the pre-defined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `set` function is executed each time the assignment happens. You are defining a recursive code. If you define a different property other than `authentication` then you don't get that error.

```
Object.defineProperty(ValueObject.prototype, "authentication", {
    get : function () {
        return this._authentication;
    },
    set : function (val) {
        this._authentication = val;
    }
});
```

Comment: is worth to mention that the exception `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` also happens on get operation