# How to fix all object values being NaN in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am currently working on a solar system physics simulator in the JavaScript canvas. I have a object named "earthState" with some info that should be used by the physics system to create earth's orbit. I have attributed a numerical value to each of the keys in the object, but when I log the object to the console it says that all values are NaN.

"earthState":

```
    let earthState = {
        distance: {
            value: 1.496 * Math.pow(10, 11),
            speed: 0.00
        },
        angle: {
            value: Math.PI/2,
            speed: 1.990986 * Math.pow(10, -7)
        }
    };

    console.log(earthState);
```

I have the object logging when the page first loads, and I have stopped the page before it finishes loading and I get the correct values in the console:

> *{distance: {…}, angle: {…}}*
>     angle: {value: 1.5707963267948966, speed: 1.9909859999999998e-7}
>     distance: {value: 149600000000, speed: 0}
>     __proto_: Object

But, as soon as I let the page finish loading, I get NaN as all the values:

> *{distance: {…}, angle: {…}}*
>     angle: {value: NaN, speed: NaN}
>     distance: {value: NaN, speed: NaN}
>     __proto_: Object

The only thing that changes when the page loads is that an animation loop starts. There are no variables that should change anything in the "earthState" object. I have had a hard time trying to figure out the problem. It may be something simple that I am not aware of. Please let me know if this is the case, and if there is anything I should change to fix this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using P5js? Also post your whole code, so we can help you better. Thanks!

Comment: You need to have some other code that causing this for instance animation code that do something like `disatance.value *= 10` and value is `"10px"`. Without looking at your actual code nothing we can do.

Comment: Just FYI `1.496 * Math.pow(10, 11)` can be written as `1.496e11`.

Comment: The "animation loop" code is clearly what's causing the problem. Without seeing that code, it's unlikely that anyone can help.

Comment: Is the object and the display in the same scope?  Try replacing let with var and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: "*There are no variables that should change anything in the "earthState" object.*" - well, but apparently there are. Use a debugger to find them, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11618278/1048572) or [there](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#watch)

Comment: @Pointy Thank you, I wasn't aware :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments and ideas! My friend has helped me debug and find the error. I was simply using the "earthState" object instead of the "sunState" object in one of the functions. Cheers!