# Function defined in debug mode immediately disappears

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

During a breakpoint, I define a function in the Console (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38646109/5231110)), but I cannot use it in the Console ("is not defined" error).

Why does a function that I just defined immediately disappear? How can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the debugger discards functions that were defined using the format `function foo() {}`, but keeps functions that were defined using the format `foo = function() {}`.

Answer (score 1):

*How can I use it?*

Method 1: First load the page, then run the snippet.

Method 2: define the function `breakOn` as a variable (anonymous function expression) if you want to successfully define it while a breakpoint is active (pointed out by 'root')

```
var breakOn = function (obj, propertyName, mode, func) {
    // this is directly from https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim
    var getPropertyDescriptor = function (obj, name) {
        var property = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, name);
        var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        while (property === undefined && proto !== null) {
            property = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, name);
            proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
        }
        return property;
    }

    var verifyNotWritable = function() {
        if (mode !== 'read')
            throw "This property is not writable, so only possible mode is 'read'.";
    }

    var enabled = true;
    var originalProperty = getPropertyDescriptor(obj, propertyName);
    var newProperty = { enumerable: originalProperty.enumerable };

    // write
    if (originalProperty.set) {// accessor property
        newProperty.set = function(val) {
            if(enabled && (!func || func && func(val)))
                debugger;
            
            originalProperty.set.call(this, val);
        }
    } else if (originalProperty.writable) {// value property
        newProperty.set = function(val) {
            if(enabled && (!func || func && func(val)))
                debugger;

            originalProperty.value = val;
        }
    } else  {
        verifyNotWritable();
    }

    // read
    newProperty.get = function(val) {
          if(enabled && mode === 'read' && (!func || func && func(val)))
            debugger;

        return originalProperty.get ? originalProperty.get.call(this, val) : originalProperty.value;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(obj, propertyName, newProperty);

    return {
      disable: function() {
        enabled = false;
      },

      enable: function() {
        enabled = true;
      }
    };
};
```

[image]

E.g. enter `breakOn(document.body, 'clientWidth', 'read')`in the console (or at the end of the snippet), continue code execution if at a breakpoint,
then access (read) the property 'clientWidth' of the document.body object in the console with `document.body.clientWidth`.

This should make the snippet code stop at the debugger statement. Now the call stack can be used to see who or what changed the property, in this case  'anonymous'.

[image]

Comment: Re "You can't run a snippet while a breakpoint is active": I disagree. I can for example run `a=1` and then `a+1` yields `2` in the console. So I can define variables. But not both kinds of functions. I'm upvoting though because this helped me make some progress, thanks!

Comment: you are right, I change the answer accordingly