# Use `Proxy` objects or getters/setters to break/pause JavaScript (DevTools) when an object changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to cause the debugger to pause whenever a certain object or a certain property of an object changes?

`watch()` has been deprecated. The recommendation (see [here](https://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ecs2041/doc/MDN_javascript_reference/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch.html) and [here](https://reference.codeproject.com/book/javascript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)) is instead to use setters and getters or [`Proxy` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

But how exaclty can `Proxy` objects be used for that? Do I have to replace some object by its proxy everywhere in the code, i.e. no way to debug pre-existing code as-is and immediately?

Same for the mentioned method using setters and getters?

`breakOn()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38646109/5231110)) seems to break only on changes of HTML elements, not JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to replace some object by its proxy everywhere in the code, i.e. no way to debug pre-existing code as-is and immediately?

That might be easiest, but it isn't the only option.

If you know exactly which object, i.e. you have a reference to it, you can replace its property with a getter/setter:

```js
const obj = { abc: 123 };

function watchProperty(obj, key) {
    const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key);
    let value = desc.value;
    Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
        enumerable: desc.enumerable,
        get() {
            console.log('GET', key);
            if (desc.writable === undefined) {
                if (desc.get) return desc.get.call(obj);
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        },
        set(val) {
            console.log('SET', key, val);
            if (desc.writable === undefined) {
                if (desc.set) desc.set.call(obj, val);
            } else if (desc.writable) {
                value = val;
            }
        },
    });
}

watchProperty(obj, 'abc');
console.log('obj.abc:', obj.abc);
obj.abc = 456;
console.log('obj.abc:', obj.abc);
```

*Based on the [ECMAScript 2022 specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver).*

Mind that to be able to use `Object.defineProperty`, the object shouldn't already have that property defined with `configurable` set to `false`. Luckily, this only happens if `Object.defineProperty` was used in the first place.

I used `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and made the property behave `obj`-specific. If your object has an inherited property, you'd have to change it in the prototype chain, but with my implementation of `watchProperty` that would lead to some weird interactions since `value` and `obj` are `obj`-specific.

That also brings me to another point: if you want to watch an (or every) instance of a class, you can watch the property on the prototype.